# What time does iOS use for Messages notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

According to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80565/what-time-is-shown-for-received-push-notification) notifications are based on the phones clock, but since that was a few years ago I'm wondering if it's changed.  Yesterday I actually got a notification 1 minute in the future.  This was from a friend with an android phone if that makes any difference, after it happened we checked the synchronization of our phones clocks and they showed the same time.

I'm wondering if Apple is doing something more complex now to determine the time?

[image]

Comment: Well the seconds could be off.